# How do I stop or limit Safari Reader from joining multiple pages into a single article?

Tags: safari

I'm developing the site suttacentral.net. We've had a report from an iOS user that when Safari reader is used on our site, it joins a large amount of pages into one "article". The site is for Buddhist discourses, one per page, so one collection can contain over a thousand pages.

I have no familiarity with Reader, so I couldn't say why it's doing this. Each page has "prev/next" links, so perhaps it's using that. Or else, since the discourses are numbered sequentially, perhaps it reads the incremented URL as the next page in an article.

So how do we stop this? It would be fine to either not join any pages, or at least to limit it to a sane number.

Comment: I would imagine it's joining based on "previous" and "next" which are usually used within articles. There's no way to change how Safari Reader functions, to my knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps not change how it functions, but I'd guess it's likely that there is some way (documented or not) to make Safari not "notice" the previous/next buttons. That would prevent it from stitching them together.